# can't cast from sqlite3_column_text16(stmt,1) to string

Tags: c++, parsing, sqlite

I'm getting errors in xcode saying:

```
No viable overload '='
```

I am trying to iterate through some code and it doesn't work.

Below is the code:

```
string query;
query = "select name from A;";
sqlite3_stmt *sqlstmt;
if(SQLITE_OK != sqlite3_prepare16_v2(db, query.c_str(),0, &sqlstmt,0)){
   sqlite3_close(db);
   return -1;
}
while(sqlite3_step(sqlstmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
  string name;
  name = sqlite3_column_text16(sqlstmt, 1);  //<--errors
  cout << name << endl;
}
```

Edit:  I added the query

Comment: probably error in your sql statement. It will be useful if you add it to your question

Comment: unlikely.  It isnt runtime error, but added it anyways.

Comment: have you tried to read the sqlite documentation on `sqlite3_column_text16`? It returns `void*` which can't be convetrted to `std::string` unless you do explicit cast

Comment: sqlite3_column_text16 returns a const void *, so i was thinking there was issues with that being cast to a string somehow.

Comment: add so what?  trying to prepend the statment with (string)sqlite_column_text16 ?

Comment: I casted it to (char*) sqlite3_column_text16(...); and the error went away.  I will need to confirm that the dataset returns actual data and NOT garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqlite3_column_text16()` returns a `void const *`, not a string.  Try this:

```
string name(static_cast<char const *>(sqlite3_column_text16(sqlstmt, 1)));
```

Note that the *16 family of functions use UTF-16, so this is unlikely to work with standard strings; you'll have to use wide strings, or the non-16 variant:

```
string name(static_cast<char const *>(sqlite3_column_text(sqlstmt, 1)));
```

Comment: the bottom sample:  string name(...); returns an error:  no matching constructor for initializtion of 'string'

Comment: Also, does that mean that i should have my prepare statement NOT be sqlite3_prepare16_v2(...), but instead sqlite3_prepare_v2(...)

Comment: I will add a cast to fix that issue.  And yes, you should be using the non-16 prepare, unless your input is UTF-16.

Comment: "static_cast from 'const unsigned char *' to 'const char *' is not allowed"

Comment: You may have to use `reinterpret_cast` then.

Comment: unfamiliar with that keyword.  Whats it do?  Or is it just a replacement for static_cast?

Comment: It's a different cast operator that interprets the byte sequence of the input using a different type.  It is different from `static_cast` in that it performs *no conversion at all*.